# Is there anyway to completely disable a webview in android

Tags: android

I want my webview to show a webpage but not to have any interaction with the page at all. 
Just show it.  I an showing an iframe but when you click on the image in it it goes to a link.  That link is to big for the frame. I need to disable being able to click it.

i have tried

```
     WebView
        android:id="@+id/wv_AmberAlert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false" 
        android:longClickable ="false"
```

and

```
    wv_Amber_Alert.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    wv_Amber_Alert.setFocusable(false);
    wv_Amber_Alert.setOnTouchListener(null);
    wv_Amber_Alert.setOnClickListener(null);
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling javascript in Webview.setJavaScriptEnabled(false), and some other method like this.

Comment: tried and no. but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try attaching a WebViewClient to the WebView and override the [onLoadResource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onLoadResource%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) method to stop loading of the url:

```
WebViewClient client = new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            view.stopLoading();
        }
    };
wv_Amber_Alert.setWebViewClient(client);
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to add an "overlay" FrameLayout over the WebView.

Make it the same size and position of your webview and **make sure android:clickable="true"**

When the webview is loading, I set my overlay to be visible. Vice versa for when loading completes.

It's also nice to add a semi-transparent background to the overlay - this explains to the user that the webview is loading and hasn't just frozen up (since interactions now dont work).